# Swift 1.2 Singleton causes App to not launch

Tags: swift, crash, singleton, launch

I have created a singleton for my iOS application to access certain things globally. When I launch the application int the simulator or on my iPhone/iPad however, it sticks on the launch screen, and never reaches the appdelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (I tried to println in it). If I remove the singleton and just leave the methods and variables  as global it works perfectly. Which leaves me to believe it's the singleton causing this crash. Here's the code I use. If I comment out the lines currently commented out it works perfectly like this "gameName" anywhere in my code but I know this isn't great practice so if I uncomment them and access the singleton like this "Global.sharedInstance.gameName" is when the app does not launch. I do call this singleton many times throughout the app so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

```
//class Global {
//
//  static let sharedInstance = Global()
//  
//  private init() {
//      println("Global Singleton created");
//  }

private var optionsModel = OptionsModel()
private var gamesModel = GamesModel()
private var savesModel = SavesModel()

var device = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).device
var screenWidth = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.bounds.width
var screenHeight = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.bounds.height
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
var PI = CGFloat(M_PI)
var gameIndex = 0
var player: AudioPlayer!
var gameLevel = ""

func loadSong(name: String, loops: Int) {
    player = AudioPlayer(name: name, loopCount: loops)
}

func playAduio(fileName: String) {
    loadSong("\(fileName)Audio", 0)
    player!.play()
}

var gameName: String {
    get {
        return gamesModel.getName(gameIndex)
    }
}

var gameDescription: String {
    get {
        return gamesModel.getDescription(gameIndex)
    }
}

var gameIntervals: NSTimeInterval {
    get {
        return gamesModel.getIntervals(gameIndex)
    }
}

var gameNeedsMic: Bool {
    get {
        return gamesModel.getMic(gameIndex)
    }
}

var gameNeedsSpeech: Bool {
    get {
        return gamesModel.getSpeech(gameIndex)
    }
}

var appLocked: Bool {
    get {
        return optionsModel.appLocked
    }
    set {
        optionsModel.appLocked = newValue
    }
}

var supervisorLoggedIn: Bool {
    get {
        return optionsModel.supervisorLoggedIn
    }
    set {
        optionsModel.supervisorLoggedIn = newValue
    }
}

var themeSongMuted: Bool {
    get {
        return optionsModel.themeSongMuted
    }
    set {
        optionsModel.themeSongMuted = newValue
    }
}

var gameCount: Int {
    get {
        return optionsModel.gameCount
    }
    set {
        optionsModel.gameCount = newValue
    }
}

var gameHighscore: Int {
    get {
        return savesModel.getHighscore(gameIndex)
    }
    set {
        savesModel.setHighscore(newValue)
    }
}

var gameStarCount: Int {
    get {
        return savesModel.getStarCount(gameIndex)
    }
    set {
        savesModel.setStarCount(newValue)
    }
}
//}
```

Comment: You show the class declaration of your Global class being commented out. Surely that's an editing error and `class Global {` should not be commented out?

Comment: Thanks but I've already fixed the problem. No this was not an error though. Creating functions and variables outside of a class makes them Global to the whole project. This was the only way i could have gotten it to work before i realized what the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Silly me. I fixed it.

The problem was that (this is probably obvious to some of you but singletons are new to me) the singleton loaded before the app delegate loaded and some of the variables in the singleton tried to get information from the app delegate before it was created so it caused this crash. Changed it around so that i didn't load the information until after the app delegate was loaded and it works now.

Comment: I was about to tell you there's most likely a loop somewhere where things just infinitely try to access each other via dependencies.